# Foreach loop is going through only a few items

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using C# to update an entity records say contacts in dynamics crm 2011. There are around 44,450 contacts exists in CRM that are active But following code snippet gone through to 500 only. Can somebody let me know what is going wrong in it.

```
foreach (Entity item in ec.Entities)
{

    if (item.Attributes.Contains("expirationdate"))
    {
        string temp1 = string.Empty;
        DateTime date;
        date = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Attributes["expirationdate"]);
        temp1 = date.Date.ToString("d");
        item.Attributes["expirationdate_hidden"] = temp1;  
    }
    service.Update(item);
}
```

Comment: does `ec.Entities` contain all the items?

Comment: How do you know it only loops 500 times?

Comment: Is there an exception that causes the loop to break?

Comment: yes, it contains all the items

Comment: I am using it in a console application and there was no exception for the loop to break

Comment: do all the items contain `expirationdate` attribute?

Comment: yes, all items contains that attribute as it is required

Comment: Does the call to service.Update alter the content of ec.Entities in some way?

Comment: yes, it alter the contents of ec.Entities

Comment: Then maybe the enumerator that is behind ec.Entities decides to stop for that reason? Does it also stop at 500 if you remove the service.Update call?

Comment: how do you know it only loops through only 500 times ?

Answer (score 2):

> replace the code with the following

```
foreach (Entity item in ec.Entities)
{

    if (item.Attributes.Contains("expirationdate"))
    {
        string temp1 = string.Empty;
        DateTime date;
        date = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Attributes["expirationdate"]);
        temp1 = date.Date.ToString("d");
        item.Attributes["expirationdate_hidden"] = temp1;  
    }
    service.Update(item);
}
```

> > if it is iterating 500 times only, than the following reason can be
> >     behind this
>
> - either the retrievemultiple returns you only 500 records it is    possible only if the maximum record which can be retrieve at the same 
>     time could is set to 500 in crm settings.

Answer (score 0):

You probably think that it only loops through `ec.Entities` because you count the number of objects that contains the `expirationdate`

Answer (score 0):

replace the foreach with a for loop and see if more than 500 items are used.
code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ec.Entities.Length; i++) 
{
     Entity item = ec.Entities[i];
     if (item.Attributes.Contains("expirationdate"))
     {
        string temp1 = string.Empty;
        DateTime date;
        date = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Attributes["expirationdate"]);
        temp1 = date.Date.ToString("d");
        item.Attributes["expirationdate_hidden"] = temp1;  
     }
     service.Update(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure you are limited in your entity retrieval but a way round this would be assigning each batch of 500 to a list.